# Loading assemblies as resources in class library

Tags: c#

I have a need to embed referenced assemblies as resources in my own library. For this I have created a little sample solution with 3 projects in it.

The first is called `First` and has no dependencies. The second is called `Second` and is dependent on `First`. The third is `OutProj` and has a reference to `Second`.

I have found [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/) article about the `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`. I have added

`[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SecondNs.Startup), "Start")]`

to my test project's AssemblyInfo class (first line after includes). Next I have defined the class and method as such:

```
class Startup
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(Resolver);
    }

    static System.Reflection.Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(','));
        byte[] block = null;
        switch (name)
        {
            case "First":
                block = Properties.Resources.First;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Assembly a2 = Assembly.Load(block);
        return a2;
    }
}
```

Both `Second` and `OutProj` have this class defined, with a difference in the switch case (the original code didn't do the trick so I modified it).

My main issue is that the Start method doesn't get called. When I add the start method code to my Main method it does indeed get called, but I don't have a Main in my class library. Is this the right approach or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The article you link to is about `ASP.NET`, and only that. It cannot be used in any other context, like a WinForms or console app.

Comment: If you want to perform initialization in a class library, either add a public method Init(), or add static constructors.

Comment: Use ILMerge first.  Something like a Nuget package next.  The GAC next.  A static constructor on a class that needs these assemblies next.  Something like Fody next.  Relying on the smarts of the client developer next.

Comment: @Maarten I will try the things you mentioned.